# Pip install is too slow

Tags: qpython, qpython3

Hello I am trying to install a few modules in Qpython but is really slow, I also tried using the alternative with Qpypi and its just really slow, my download rate is between 5KBs and 10KBs...

I am using a Samsung 10+
Android Version 11
QPython 3L

The modules that I am trying to download are numpy and pandas.

[Here is a screenshot of the console...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxx77.jpg)